# How to stop parent div from stretching to height of child div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
#container {
  height: 70%;
  background-color: red;
}

#childContainer {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  height: 20% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="childContainer">
      <div class="child"><h1>Title</h1><p>Paragraph</p></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>Title</h1><p>Paragraph</p></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>Title</h1><p>Paragraph</p></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>Title</h1><p>Paragraph</p></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>Title</h1><p>Paragraph</p></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>Title</h1><p>Paragraph</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Without the h1 and p elements in the child div, the code works as expected. However these elements seem to be affecting the height of each child div, which is in turn stretching the childContainer

Comment: You have a class `.child` that's not applied anywhere in your example.

Comment: the divs are added via javascript. the class is added to those divs in js

Comment: Show the added divs in a "working" example that shows the problem more exactly.

Comment: there. edited to include the javascript

Comment: We didn't need the js, just the final html so we could see what you were talking about. [Minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Which means, we don't need 100 divs, just enough to show the problem. 1 div? 2 divs?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/kLQWsik.png

Comment: the number of divs is random. if i hardcode some placeholder divs into the html the problem isnt reproducable. so i put 100 there because its relevant

Comment: my mistake. will fix it now

Comment: the #container and the #childContainer have different heights, this is why the problem of background color arises. Make the container stretch to full height.

Comment: the container should be 70% of the browser window. the childContainer should be 100% of the container

Comment: also the problem has nothing to do with the background color

Comment: Can you provide the basic idea of your output?

Comment: hi, im sorry, i fixed it. the problem was that another container, which wasnt included in the example code, was set to 100% along with the html and body tags. i switched that to 100vh instead and that solved the issue.